# Crash in Exact Target Push Android SDK 4.5.0

Tags: marketing-cloud, android

When including the Instabug SDK and:

```
 compile ('com.exacttarget.etpushsdk:etsdk:4.5.0@aar'){
        transitive = true
    }
```

We are consistently seeing the following error

> E/AndroidRuntime:FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 Process: xxOurAppxx,
>   PID: 23714
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
>       at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Does not happen if just InstaBug SDK or just ExactTarget SDK are included.

Comment: This is specific to Salesforce - the inclusion of your SDK is causing a crash.

Comment: Appears to be a conflict between the Instabug SDK and ETPush SDK, the build variants that don't include both don't exhibit the crash.

Comment: Updating from Instabug 2.3.3 to 2.6.2  appears to fix the conflict (they excluded GCM in 2.5.0).

Comment: This definitely IS <-- caps for emphasis a Salesforce related question.  Please stop flagging MobilePush SDK questions as off topic.